# how to access a report server from VS2010 and how to implement in multi tier architecture

Tags: asp.net, multi-tier, reportserver

I am developing a website where user logs in and access different reports from report server

A WCF service to be developed to access the ssrs report and it returns to the UI ( what it should return to report viewer control it should be a dataset or ?)

So how can i implement this with N-tier architecture. 
and how can i design the report.Can anyone explain in brief ? please

I found in google how to access a report in remote server but how implement in multi tier architecture

Comment: I suggest putting the reports on SharePoint so that no coding needs to be done.

Comment: what? That is not the rek...i need info for my rek

Comment: KISS is what you should always think about first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you need to explain the needs for putting report server behind WCF services. IMO, the simplest thing is to make your web site use Report Viewer control to access reports from report server. In such configuration, your report server need not be exposed to users so I am unclear as to what can be purpose for using WCF services in between.

However, for whatever reasons, you must have WCF services as facade over report server then you have to wrap report server web services in your WCF services, you have two choices here:

- Don't use report viewer. Build your own report UI that will call WCF services. Essentially, your service need to return report content (html) for the given page. Report Server Web Services expose methods that gives report output in particular format (and for some page). For export functionality, your service essentially have to return entire report in particular format. This way, you will have control over your service interface
- Second way is to replicate the interface of report server web services as is in your WCF services. Mind you, it means matching the API style which I believe is a REST style API. In such, you can use Report Viewer in UI because it is designed to work against report server API. So it should work as long as your WCF servies offer exactly the same interface.